# Jquery - Display value of user input live

Tags: jquery

Similar to Stack Overflow, I'm trying to create a `jquery` method that records and displays the value of what a user enters into an `<input type='text'>` field.

```
<form>
  Language:</br>
  <input type="text" language="language">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<p>
</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").keypress(function () {
      $("p").text($(":text").val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

It accurately records the correct value, but it is one step too slow. If I type in a first character, it doesn't show up, but after I type in a second character, only the first character is recorded. If I type in 3 characters, the first 2 are recorded, etc.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to bind the event to the `keyup` event

```
<form>
  Language:</br>
  <input type="text" language="language">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<p>
</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").keyup(function () {
      $("p").text($(":text").val());
    });
  });
</script>
```

According to the jQuery docs:
Note: as the `keypress` event isn't covered by any official specification, the actual behavior encountered when using it may differ across browsers, browser versions, and platforms.

Comment: I see, the `keyup` event is different than the `keypress` event.

Comment: `keypress` event is fired when a key is pressed. The moment you press a key, that character has not been written into the input yet. That is why if you immediately call `val()` on keypress, it returns the value without the pressed key.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":text").keyup(function () {
      $("p").text($(":text").val());
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Language:</br>
  <input type="text" language="language">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a jQuery plugin.

```js
$.fn.bindTo = function(element) {
  $(this).keyup(function() {
    element.text($(this).val());
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").bindTo($("#output"));
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="input">Input:</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" language="language">
  <br />
  <label for="output">Output:</label>
  <span id="output"></span>
</form>
```